# Bootstrap 3 add label to cell in table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, customization

I did a fiddle to add a label inside a table cell.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m39n5sm8/)

I'm trying to add a green label to my first row but it's very ugly I'm very bad in design and if you resize the browser my label go out. Do you have any suggestion to make this better ?

I do that because I have to tell to the user that this row was edited in my app.

```
.customrow{
  margin-top:-11px;
  margin-left:-43px;
  padding-top:13px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so you want that green label always left align in that td, right?

Comment: How about you use "badge class" from bootstrap!

Comment: just remove border-radius; and it will be ok. But design is very subjective.

Comment: Yes I need that or any suggestion if you have a better idea

Comment: But there is a problem with my position absolute. Try to resize the page and the label go out :/ and I think it's really bad to use negative margin, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, i just made a class `leftrow` for the span and applied custom css

```
.leftrow{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:30%;
  line-height: 200%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#5CB85C;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m39n5sm8/2/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is nice ! But there is a problem on the label if I resize the browser

Comment: And what is the problem, can you explain it?

Comment: If you resize the page you will see than the green span become smaller and the M inside the span go out the label. Maybe we should fix the width of the green span

Comment: I think you will be facing text overflow outside the label when resize the browser. I just updated the jsFiddle. I added font-size to 2vw

Answer (score 1):

You could use boostrap `badge` class or simply highlight the cell

I have demonstrated my two suggestions in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m39n5sm8/4/)